# How to simulate asset prices/returns that display market regimes?

Tags: asset-pricing, numerical-methods, asset-returns, market-regimes

Are there any techniques that can make a multivariate random number generating process for stock prices/returns, like **geometric Brownian motion via Cholesky**, also include the simulation of a finite number of market regimes (say 2 or 3) so that systematic (market-induced) movement in prices are experienced across all assets for the same span of time intervals? (e.g. observations/prices 1-250 are market regime 1 for all assets, prices 251-400 are regime 2, etc)

For the univariate case, I understand that simulated returns can be generated from separate Gaussian distributions, each of which represents a "bullish" or "bearish" market regime, with:

1. the returns for the **bullish regime** drawn from a Guassian distribution with positive mean and low variance,
2. while returns for the **bearish regime** draw from a Gaussian distribution with slight negative mean but higher variance,

but my question pertains to generating *multivariate* artificial returns instead of one-by-one univariate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a "statistical mechanics" approach - paper at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04925.pdf and code at https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72000-canonical-ensemble-for-time-series

From the paper abstract:

"*This consists of a statistical mechanical approach - analogous to the configuration model for networked systems - for ensembles of time series **designed to preserve**, on average, **some of the statistical properties** observed on an empirical set **of time series***" (highlights mine)

Some of these properties may very well be bull or bearish regimes.

EDIT - in response to develarist's comment
[image: Figure 1 from above linked paper]

Comment: could you explain the statistical mechanics approach in a paragraph. what does it entail

Comment: In the newly added figure, where do the regimes come in?

Comment: By editing the original "observed set of time series W_bar" to meet your requirements of regime 1, 2, 3 etc. along and across W_bar. Then, your P(W) multivariate, artificial returns will, to a high probability, match your original, edited W_bar time series set. In the figure you can imagine the two colours, orange and turquoise, to represent two different regimes.